# Cisco 2504 Wireless Controller Setup

Tags: cisco, wireless, cisco-wireless, access-point

I'm attempting to set up a Cisco 2504 Wireless Controller for personal use (50+ connections to access point) and I'm having trouble accessing the configuration page.  Before the wireless controller, we had an ASUS router set up and whenever we attempt to access the configuration page of the controller, we see a failed attempt to connect to the configuration page of the ASUS router.
We've attempted rebooting the router, but we get the same page.
My thought is that for whatever reason, we're using the wrong ip address to access the GUI.
Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What IP did you put on the controller?  If you have not configured an IP, use a Cisco console cable to do that

Comment: @MikePennington Originally it was 192.168.1.1, but the guy that went through the setup wizard might have changed it. I'm not sure. Can I use an Ethernet cable or is using the Cisco console cable necessary?